# Add more field in a document without overwrite in Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wish to add fields in my firebase without overwriting it.

As you can see below, the user for my app will screen their emotions and the emotion will be uploaded to firebase.
Actually, user will be screened many times and each time they will get different emotions or same emotions.

[image]

Lets say the user screened their face and get Happiness, Sadness, Happiness respectively.

I wish to have my fields in the firebase console like this:

FaceEmotion: Happiness

FaceEmotion: Sadness

FaceEmotion: Happiness

Using my code below, at this moment I only get to overwrite the (FaceEmotion:) with same emotion values but not adding values as I wish like above. I've tried using array but I guess the problem is because the fieldname "FaceEmotion" is the same.
Is there a way for me to let Firestore generate autoID for the fieldname "FaceEmotion"? like maybe to have something like this:

FaceEmotion1: Happiness

FaceEmotion2: Sadness

FaceEmotion3: Happiness

```
String Emotion = EmotionType.toString();

userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
FaceEmotion = "FaceEmotion";

Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("FaceEmotion",Emotion);

DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID).collection("FaceEmotion").document(FaceEmotion);

documentReference.update("FaceEmotion",FieldValue.arrayUnion(user)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Data has been saved "+ userID);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail what you want the outcome of this code to be.  What do exactly do you want the document to look like?  What does it mean to "add values"?

Comment: Is it more clearer now? But actually if you read my post you will understand how I want the outcome to look like @DougStevenson

Comment: A document just can't have multiple fields with the same name.  Consider instead using an array type field to hold multiple values, or use multiple documents per user.

Comment: May I get an insight on how to do that please. If you wish to help adjusting my codes above for that, that will be more helpful. thank you anyway for informing that I cant have multiple fields with same name. @DougStevenson

Comment: Please checked my edited post above. I managed to use array but when the user consistently get the same emotion in many tries, the array wont updated. I think its because the same field name. Can I know how to get auto-generated field name? @DougStevenson

Answer (score 2):

The issue is on how you are writing to the document, the solution is to create a new document for every new emoton, this way you will be able to add emotions to that collection.

The code to write the emotions with this modification would be something like:

```
String emotion = EmotionType.toString();

userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
faceEmotion = "FaceEmotion";

Map<String,Object> val = new HashMap<>();
    val.put("FaceEmotion",emotion);


DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID).collection("FaceEmotion").document();

documentReference.set(val).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Data has been saved "+ userID);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                    }
                });
```